# RestKit: RKManagedObjectRequestOperation with no mappingResult when operation fails

Tags: swift, restkit

I am using RestKit in a swift project. 
In my `RKObjectManager` I am setting the following `RKResponseDescriptor`:

```
var responseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(
                               mapping: PPAMappingProvider.responseMapping, 
                               method: RKRequestMethod.Any, 
                               pathPattern: nil, 
                               keyPath: "meta", 
                               statusCodes: nil)
self.addResponseDescriptor(responseDescriptor)
```

Basically, all my API requests return a `meta` object. I have other mappings to match the `result`, and everything works fine.
When a POST/PUT is successful (status code 200), my API returns something like:

```
{"meta":{"msg":"Success","ts":1417004530608},
 "result":{"_id":"H7mLYJc","user_id":1000,...}}
```

If it is not successful (status code 404), it returns e.g.:

```
{"meta":{"msg":"Item not found.","ts":1417004403903}}
```

According to the [documentation](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKResponseDescriptor.html#//api/name/statusCodes), when I set `statusCodes: nil`, the mapping should work with all status codes, even 404. The problem is that it doesn't, I have to add the code:

```
responseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(
                               mapping: PPAMappingProvider.responseMapping, 
                               method: RKRequestMethod.Any, 
                               pathPattern: nil, 
                               keyPath: "meta", 
                               statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(UInt(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)))
self.addResponseDescriptor(responseDescriptor)
```

(notice the `statusCodes` parameter) if I want this mapping to work on 404 responses. By the way, I am using these mappings with `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation`, but that shouldn't matter does it?
When the server returns status code 200, these mapping work perfectly.

It's not a big deal, since I got this to work. I just wanted to know if I am doing anything wrong, or if this is a bug to send to RestKit?

Comment: In theory, it should work as you expect. What version of RK are you using? Have you debugged in the response descriptor match method?

Comment: Thanks @Wain. At the time I had to move to other stuff and didn't get the opportunity to debug. I'll try to do it soon.